# How to use the a and i command in Gnu sed to add a newline character using \n?

Tags: sed

In below example, I can use the literal newline characters to add an empty line before and after `3`. Is it possible to use `\n` instead? I'm using Gnu sed 4.5.

```
root@u1804:~# seq 5 | sed -r -e '/3/{i\
> ' -e 'a\
> ' -e '}'
1
2

3

4
5
root@u1804:~#
```

Comment: Haha, sorry to bother you again. I'm learning sed right now and I just want to make the command a little bit cleaner. If I can use \n instead of a literal newline, I can write the command in a single line, which will make it easy to type and read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `\n` it will work but you'll end up with two newlines before and after as the commands `i\` and `a\` already add a newline before and respectively after the pattern space is printed so

```
seq 5 | sed  -e '3i\\n' -e '3a\\n'
```

prints

```
1
2


3


4
5
```

If, for some reason, you want it in one-line you can use multiple `-e`xpressions:

```
seq 5 | sed  -e '3{i\' -e '' -e 'a\' -e '' -e '}'
```

though in this case it's easier/shorter to just use the hold space:

```
 seq 5 | sed  '3{G;H;x;}'
```

Comment: ... or (with GNU sed) `{G;H;z;x;}` if you need the hold space to be returned to its initial - empty - state after